# Position a floated div vertically within text

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm attempting to find a pure CSS solutions to create an article with a featured quote section that starts `50px` (or so) down the page. This section should be `50%` width and the text should wrap around it (top and bottom).

Current I have the standard float solution, where it appears at the top of the text.

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/06p3e5Lh/1/)**

```css
.inset-text {
    display:block;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: pink;
    margin: 0 5% 2% 0;
}
```

Comment: Show your expected output. like in an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about another `div` wrapper and a bit of top padding and negative margin?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/06p3e5Lh/7/)**

HTML

```
<div class="article-container">
    <div class="inset-text">
        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>
    <div class="article-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.article-container {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.inset-text {
    /* display:block; */
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background: pink;
    /* margin: 0 5% 2% 0; */
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.article-text {
    margin-top: -50px;
}

/*
Because of the top padding set to the article-container the top margin of the first 
p element does not collapse anymore. So just set the top margin to 0.
*/
.article-text p:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```